# JSON Decode of Arrays and Dictionaries in Swift Model

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

For some reason, I can't seem to decode the following JSON from an API, probably because my model is not right for the JSON:

```
{"definitions":[{"type":"noun","definition":"the larva of a 
butterfly.","example":null,"image_url":null,"emoji":null},
{"type":"adjective","definition":"brand of heavy equipment.","example":null,"image_url":null,"emoji":null}],
"word":"caterpillar","pronunciation":"ˈkadə(r)ˌpilər"}
```

Here is my model:

```
struct DefinitionReturned : Codable {
        let Definition : [Definition]
        let word : String
        let pronunciation : String

    }
    struct Definition : Codable {
        let type: String
        let definition: String
        let example: String?
        let image_url: String?
        let emoji : String?
    }
```

The code to decode is:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

                do {

                    let somedefinitions = try JSONDecoder().decode(DefinitionReturned.self, from: data)
                    print("here are the definitions",somedefinitions)
}
```

The error is:

```
ERROR IN DECODING DATA
The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Definition", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Definition\", intValue: nil) (\"Definition\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Of note, there can be one or more definitions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `let Definition : [Definition]` => `let definitions : [Definition]` because in your JSON, it's `definitions` (starting with a lowercase and pluarls). If you want to keep it as such, you need to define the codingkeys, but I wouldn't recommend it, since the naming is more iOS like with `definitions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// MARK: - DefinitionReturned
struct DefinitionReturned: Codable {
    let definitions: [Definition]
    let word, pronunciation: String
}

// MARK: - Definition
struct Definition: Codable {
    let type, definition: String
    let example, imageURL, emoji: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type, definition, example
        case imageURL = "image_url"
        case emoji
    }
}
```

Then decode

```
let definitionReturned = try? JSONDecoder().decode(DefinitionReturned.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: sorry my fault ...  @koen .. thank you for identification:)